# How is Serilog.Extras.Web's ApplicationLifecycleModule getting automatically registered?

Tags: asp.net, serilog

Quoting the Serilog Wiki:

> The ApplicationLifecycleModule will automatically be enabled...

Okay, great. How is this happening? It's not listed in the `<modules/>` element of web.config and there's no references to it in my code anywhere. So what and where is the magic that wires it all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic is `[PreApplicationStartMethod]` in https://github.com/serilog-web/classic/blob/master/src/SerilogWeb.Classic/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L9

Comment: With the recent refactoring, the source has moved to https://github.com/serilog-web/classic/blob/master/src/SerilogWeb.Classic/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L9